# Gcm delivery not guaranteed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM service for my android chat application, sometimes the message sent without any problem and sometimes it fail without any Ack nor Nack..
I don't change any thing, the network is souitable the message is the same as the previuse...
Why does GCM send sometimes and fail sometimes in the same conditions!

point:  I send many types of messages other than the chat messages thet the user write directory.
for example I send: ( online status, typing status, profile photo changed...ect)...
these messages sent to my xmpp server via GCM...

does these (many) messages make GCM stop for a while?
I set delay_while_idle = true and TTL=0

sorry for my English I hope you got me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found that it's common issue in GCM, i.e this is the behavior of GCM.. delay, random thrulling.. I can call this Bug in GCM although the GCM team see that this delays and thrulling are normal and ok ...
So I would like to find alternative...
I found one platforma that not depents to GCM :
http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2013/10/acs-push-notification-using-gcm.html?m=1